# How to distinguish quadratic ramified extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, local-field

Let $p \not = 2$ be an odd prime number. I am trying to understand how to characterize isomorphism classes of quadratic ramified extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$.

Any such extension $E$ is isomorphic to a field of the form $\mathbb Q_p(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the root of a quadratic Eisenstein polynomial $A(X) \in \mathbb Q_p[X]$. Such polynomials (which we can assume to be monic) are given by
$$A(X) = X^2 + paX + pu,$$
where $a\in \mathbb Z_p$ and $u \in \mathbb Z_p^{\times}$.

I have read in notes online that by studying the structure of the quotient group $\mathbb Q_p^{\times} / (\mathbb Q_p^{\times})^2$, one can classify all quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$. It turns out that there are only two isomorphism classes of ramified quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$. One isomorphism class is given by $E_1 := \mathbb Q_p[\sqrt{p}]$, corresponding to the choice of Eisenstein polynomial $X^2-p$.

**Question 1:** How exactly does the quotient group $\mathbb Q_p^{\times} / (\mathbb Q_p^{\times})^2$ relate to the problem of constructing quadratic extensions? The notes I mentioned above do not make this process explicit.

**Question 2:** What would a representative $E_2$ of the other isomorphism class look like?

**Question 3:** Given an abstract Eisenstein polynomial $A(X)$ as above and $E$ the associated quadratic ramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, how can I determine whether $E$ is isomorphic to $E_1$ or $E_2$?

**Bonus question:** Do we have a formula for the number of isomorphism classes of ramified extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$ of a given degree $d \geq 2$? And similarly, is there a computational method to distinguish between them, generalizing the quadratic case?

Comment: 1. is called Kummer theory. It’s pretty wide with many formulations. Here’s one: to $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$ you associate $\mathbb{Q}_p(x^{1/2})$. Then you can recover $\mathbb{Q}_p \times x^{1/2}$ as the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ of the only nontrivial automorphism. 2. follows from 1. once you know the structure of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$. For 3., I need to think about it. For the bonus, unless there’s a typo and you meant “ramified”, it’s always $1$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you for the answers, I will look for lecture notes on Kummer theory. For the bonus question, there was indeed a typo: I meant ramified extensions. It is fixed now

Comment: For 3., considering the class of $E(0)$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times} /\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2}$ should invert the Kummer construction I was talking about. The bonus question becomes a lot trickier, as essentially all extensions are ramified, and most of the tricks above stop working (because Kummer theory just crashes and its more sophisticated variant local class field theory just isn’t up to the task). I still guess that a lot of things are known on this topic, but nothing specific and nontrivial comes to my mind.

Comment: If $d | p-1$ then the cyclic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ of degree $d$ correspond to the subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times} /\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times d}$ of order $d$ and the unramified one corresponds to the subgroup generated by $\zeta_{p-1}$.

Comment: The main argument is that a generator $\sigma$ of the Galois group is diagonalizable in $End_{\Bbb{Q}_p}(E)$ and its eigenvalues are a group that must be the whole of $\langle \zeta_d\rangle$, the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times} /\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times d}$ is that of eigenelements ie. $\langle a^d\rangle$ where $\sigma(a)=\zeta_d a$. If the extension is unramified then the same holds in the extension of residue fields so that $a$ can be chosen to be a root of unity.

Comment: I meant the cyclic subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times} /\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times d}$ of order $d$ and $d$-th power of eigenelements.

Comment: I would also consider following the low road. A) We are in characteristic zero, so any quadratic extension is gotten by adjoining the square root of some element. B) $K(\sqrt a)=K(\sqrt b)$ if and only if $a/b$ is a square in $K$. C) By item B we can infer that you only need to look at the fields $\Bbb{Q}_p(\sqrt a)$ where $a$ is a either a $p$-adic unit or $p$ times a $p$-adic unit. In the former case the extension will be unramified, and (given that $p>2$) there will be only one, pick $a$ such that $\overline{a}\in\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ is a quadratic non-residue.

Comment: (cont'd) C) Similarly adjoining $\sqrt{ap}$ or $\sqrt{au^2p}$ results in identical ramified extension, so you only need to consider whether $\overline{a}$ is or is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$.